# Intel Rapid Storage Technology undo

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid

When I installed Windows 7 on this computer, I saw Intel Rapid Storage Technology on it, and I created a Volume of the two drives in this computer thinking that this would like combine the size of the two drives into one pseudodrive. But that didn't happen, it doesn't seem to have done anything at all and now my second drive is gone. Is there a way to undo the Volumes and Arrays in Intel Rapid Storage Technology?

Comment: If you created an array you will still have to extend the windows partition in disk management for windows to see the extra space.

Comment: ..and how do you do that? More detailed answers -_-

Comment: Not an answer it's a comment for a reason... I don't always have time to write out proper answers.. You can google windows disk management. But I'll tell you since you seem pretty lazy: go to administrative tools in control panel then computer management. You should see disk management in the computer management MMC. IF you need detailed answer with pictures then google is your best bet.

Comment: Yeha, I already did it and it worked, but unfortunately that's not what I wanted. I mean it did combine the disks, like I originally wanted, but now I want to undo everything and get two seperate disks, and there's no way I can find to do it in Intel RST

Comment: Or you can just type 'disk management' into the Start Menu...the search functionality is there for a reason, kids! :)

Comment: Well you probably need shrink the partition first but if it's a raid 0 your screwed since it stripes the data across both disks neither of your disk now have complete data so you will have to rebuild... sorry.

Comment: Also if you already "did that" then you should see all of your space and if you already have been in disk management why did you ask for more detailed instructions? Your comments really confuse me.

Comment: Okay, so I might have to reinstall my OS again? =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What KIND of volume did you make (this is the **very first thing it asks you**, as I recall)?  There are multiple kinds of RAID arrays available - it sounds like you made a RAID1 array, which is for redundancy, when you meant to make a RAID0 array, which is for increased capacity/speed.

You should be able to select the array and change the type (or disable entirely) from the RST interface.

EDIT: If this is the current active system volume (i.e., Windows is installed on it) there's no way to easily disable a RAID0 this after the fact.  You'll need to change it from the RAID BIOS (usually Ctrl+I as the system is booting up for Intel controllers), but this will completely wipe the contents of the drives.  You need to either clone the installation off to a third drive, and then clone it back on, or just format and start from scratch.

Comment: I would if I could but there are no options for changing or disabling it

Comment: and it is RAID 0

Comment: If you open RST, select 'Manage' and then the array, you don't have 'Change Type' next to "RAID0"?  If it's in RAID0, and configured properly, then you should see a single drive that's the combined size of the other drives.  If it's not the right size, you may need to extend the partition - launch Disk Management from the Start Menu and you should see pretty plainly what disks Windows thinks you have.

Comment: (If you're running off this RAID0 you may not be able to change it on the fly, but I assume you're not because I think RST would have complained about this...but I've never tried.  That would explain why it might not let you change it, though, but anything else will require changing things outside the OS.)

Comment: Okay, well yeah, I was able to extend my disk size to the full size of the Volume in RST, however, I want to undo it and have my two seperate disks again, but there is no way to undo RST

Comment: Mark, I should have asked more explicitly - is Windows installed on the RAID0 volume?

Comment: Yes, Windows is installed on C:/ which is in the Volume

Comment: @Mark - See my edit.  You'll have to start from scratch unless you have another drive available.  This really isn't the sort of thing you should be playing around with unless you know what you're doing, I'm afraid.

Comment: You have to learn somehow, right? Now I know all about HDD arrays, I've built a few for clients with servers but if I hadn't made this mistake I never would have even learned it.

Comment: @MarkKramer - Oh, absolutely, but I think my comment at the time was more of the tenor of "if this is at all important to you and/or needs to be up and running it's way easier to just wipe it" not "don't touch this you'll break something" ;)